# separar por comas un array para hacer consulta sql

Tags: sql, vb.net

Estoy haciendo uso de un array en VB.NET, despues lo paso a una query sql de selección de la siguiente forma

```
SELECT * FROM empresa WHERE factura IN ('" & val & "')
```

donde val es un array, pero el inconveniente es que cada valor del array debe ser separado por comas para poderlo usar en la query anterior, ¿Como puedo hacer para pasar el array separado por comas?, esta es la forma en que guardo mi array

```
Dim array() As String = {factura}

For Each value As String In array
    Dim val
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) Then
     val = value + ","
    Else
    val = value

    End If
    consultaEnvio = db.Query("SELECT * FROM empresa WHERE             factura IN ('" & val & "')")

    For Each A In consultaEnvio
    MsgBox(A("NOMBRE")+A("FACTURA"))
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrias usar

```
Dim array() As String = {factura}

Dim filtroIN As String = String.Join(",", array)

consultaEnvio = db.Query("SELECT * FROM empresa WHERE factura IN (" & filtroIN & ")")

For Each A In consultaEnvio
    MsgBox(A("NOMBRE")+A("FACTURA"))
Next
```

con el String.Join() podrias unir un array con un separador

Comment: si deseo que los datos que regresa la query se muestren todos y no uno por uno ¿como le podría hacer?

Comment: pero para mostrarlos todos deberias asignarlos a un control de lista

Comment: ahhh ok haber lo intento

Answer (score 0):

Una vez llenado tu arreglo deberías recorrerlo y crear tu cadena que enviaras dentro del `in`

```vb
Dim cadenaIn As String =  ""
For Each value As String In array
    cadenaIn = cadenaIn & value & ","
next    
cadenaIn = left(cadenaIn,(Len(cadenaIn)-1))'aca eliminamos la coma del ultimo elemento
consultaEnvio = db.Query("SELECT * FROM empresa WHERE factura IN ('" & cadenaIn & "')")

For Each A In consultaEnvio
    MsgBox(A("NOMBRE")+A("FACTURA"))
Next
```

Comment: creo que la respuesta de http://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2600/leandro-tuttini es mas elegante y mas optima

Comment: Solís Guzman si deseo que los datos que regresa la query se muestren todos y no uno por uno ¿como le podría hacer?

Comment: deberias hacer un ciclo igual en el que llenes una variable con la estructura que quieres mostrar, algo parecido a lo que yo hago para darle formato al arreglo

Comment: ya le intente pero no me queda

Comment: Dim resultado As String =  ""                                                                      For Each A In consultaEnvio
    resultado = resultado &"Nombre: "& A("NOMBRE") &"Factura" &A("FACTURA"))
Next                                                                                                                  Msgbox(resultado)

Answer (score 0):

Ya te ha contestado Leandro de manera excelente, aporto con otro ejemplo del mismo tipo.

```
Dim sqlquery As String
Dim sqlquerys As New ArrayList()
```

' Ahí definis primero el "encabezado" de la consulta y el array que utilizarás.

```
sqlquery = "INSERT INTO FERIANTES(Nombre, Apellido) VALUES "
For x = 0 To ListaDeFeriantes.Count - 1
Dim CONSULTA As String = ""
CONSULTA = "('" & ListaDeFeriantes.Nombre & "," & ListaDeFeriantes.Apellido & ")"
sqlquerys.Add(CONSULTA)
Next
sqlquerys.ToArray()
Dim strCommand As String = [String].Join(",", sqlquerys.ToArray())
```

' Y finalmente la consulta la unirás con:

```
Dim ConsultaFinal as String = sqlquery & strCommand
```